# How to update spreadsheet bound script using AppScript API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I intend to update my bound script (destination) with contents from another script (source). I am trying the following code. It does not give any error, but do not modify the destination script either.

```
function getScriptSourceCode() {
var srcProjectId = "id of source project"; // Source project ID
var destProjectId = "id of destination project"
var baseUrl = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects";
var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
var srcName = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/" + srcProjectId,       {
 method: "get",
 headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
 }).getContentText()).title;

 var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/" + srcProjectId + "/content", {
 method: "get",
 headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
  }).getContentText();

var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + destProjectId   
 + "/content";

var  options = {
followRedirects: true,
"method" : "PUT",
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
"headers": {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
 },
 "contentType": "application/json",
 "payload": JSON.stringify(content)
}      
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  }
}
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Is your script the latest one? Because I think that when the project is saved after your script was copied and pasted, an error occurs. And also ``srcName`` is not used. If you have the other latest script, could you please update your question? And also, if you modified the Manifests file (appsscript.json), please provide the information.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for the erroneous script. I modified the script little bit and now its working as desired. However it seems I have to run the script twice to get the desired result. Below is the working  script.

```
function UpdateScript() 
{
  var destProjectId = "Destination project ID"
  var srcProjectId = "Source Project ID"; // Source project ID
  var baseUrl = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects";
  var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()

  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/" + srcProjectId + "/content", {
  method: "get",
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
  }).getContentText();

  // Upload a project to bound-script project.
 var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/" + destProjectId + "/content", {
  method: "put",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken},
  payload: content
 }).getContentText());

}
```